# How to read through all rows and populate GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following c# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    //Get Parent Task
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryStringParent, connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fkobjectid) && fkobjectid != "&nbsp;")
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            gvParentTasks.DataSource = reader;
            gvParentTasks.DataBind();
        }
        while (reader.read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If only populates the GridView (`gvParentTasks`) with the first row. How can I use the `while (reader.read())` to read all the rows and populate the GridView for all the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SqlDataAdapter` instead and fill a `DataSet` then populate the `GridView`:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    //Get Parent Task
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryStringParent, connection);
    connection.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fkobjectid) && fkobjectid != "&nbsp;")
    {
        da.Fill(ds);

        gvParentTasks.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gvParentTasks.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're actually making it harder then you need to do it.  You can create a page on your front-end.  All you have to do is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="sdsOrderReview" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ECommerceDB %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [OrderId], [AccountId], [Name]
        FROM [Order] ORDER BY [OrderId] DESC">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

That is a simple example, then for your Grid View, all you need to do:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvOrder" runat="server" DataSourceId=sdsOrderReview">
```

Then it will automatically fill your grid with the data from your query.  Plus it will exist through the entire page state.  By doing it through the backend, you'll have to ensure it is called at Page-Load as you can run into persist issues.

Comment: The DataSource is using string from the CommandArgument but this is great. I will keep in mind for next time :) Thank you

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You can actually pass CommandArguement through the front-end as well.  Which will couple to the backend either through a Web-Method or Postback.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `while (reader.read())` from your code and you should see the data from `DataReader`

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
gvParentTasks.DataSource = reader;
gvParentTasks.DataBind();
```

Comment: It only displays one row only :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, just try the code above, without any checks, it should display all the rows in `DataReader`, make sure you are getting back multiple rows from the query

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach: use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead to fill a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryStringParent, connection))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    // you don't need to open/close the connection with Fill
    da.Fill(data);
}
gvParentTasks.DataSource = data;
gvParentTasks.DataBind();
```

However, it should also work to use the `SqlDataSource` as `DataSource` for the `GridView` directly:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
gvParentTasks.DataSource = reader;
gvParentTasks.DataBind();
```

I assume that the reason for your issue is this:

```
while (reader.read())
{
}
```

It *consumes* all records.